# bash Here document to long

Tags: bash, sh

I have run into this issue where i have a here doc in a function but bash does not see it as a function as the here doc is long

eg:

line 25

```
function write_p_configs {

cat /usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf <<EOL
    really long document up to 50 lines
EOL
}
```

line 70

```
write_p_configs
```

I get an error saying write_p_configs command not found but if i remove half of whats in the here doc it works seem to only give off the error when the here doc is long, in sublime text clicking inside the function does not have the underline showing the {} match.

what would be the best fix for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do in this function?

Comment: What makes you think the here doc is too long? I'm not aware of any size limits, and "up to 50 lines" really isn't very big. If you got an error message, please update your question to show us what it is. If you didn't, tell us what went wrong.

Comment: the reason I'm thinking the doc is to long as bash says command not found when trying to run the function if i have a long conf file to be written out. Unless its something inside the here doc like spacing or # comments?

Comment: @ChrisR: If you want me to see a comment, you need to include my name preceded by an at-sign; I only saw this one by chance. Show us the entire function; 50 lines isn't that much. But first, try to figure out exactly what you need to delete to make the problem go away. There may be one particular line that's causing the problem -- but we can't guess without seeing it. A 50-line here document is not too long, and bash isn't saying that it is.

Comment: Try use cat <<'EOL' - maybe you have something in the heredoc what causes error. the 'EOL' (in single quotes) disables any interpolation

Comment: @KeithThompson here is a link to the whole file https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fwynuv8sd1qyn3/php.sh i found removing any part of the code to make the function smaller works :S

Comment: I downloaded it; it's quite different from what you described. The file contains two function definitions, but it doesn't do anything with them. The here doc is over 500 lines not 50, though the size still shouldn't be a problem. The functions are called `write_php-fpm_initd` and `write_php_configs`, not `write_p_configs`. Are you sure you're invoking it with `bash`? `sh` likely won't accept hyphens in function names. Try modifying the script so it writes only to files in the current directory (I don't want to create `/usr/local/php` et al on my system), and ...

Comment: ... put the entire script on Dropbox, and let us know *exactly* what error message you get when you run it. Make sure it has `#!/bin/bash` at the top. When I run `bash php.sh` on my system, it does nothing, which is what I'd expect.

Comment: @KeithThompson The script does nothing apart from defining two functions.  It doesn't invoke any of those.  The `heredoc` doesn't have anything to do here.  Unless you invoke any of the functions the script wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @devnull: Yes, that's pretty much what I said.

Answer (score 1):

It *appears* (the name of the function suggests) that you're trying to write several lines to `/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf` using a `heredoc`.  Your command:

```
cat /usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf <<EOL
    really long document up to 50 lines
EOL
```

is essentially equivalent to saying:

```
cat <<EOL
    really long document up to 50 lines
EOL
```

You need to *redirect* the output of `cat` to the desired file:

```
cat >/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf <<EOL
    really long document up to 50 lines
EOL
```

Comment: I have updated with what you said but still no luck i have updated my question with more info on the error message.